# Android adapter.addFrag not accepting more than one of my fragments

Tags: android, fragment, toolbar

I'm following this tutorial [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/) trying to add fragments to a tabbed Android app but it doesn't accept more than one fragment when I do it.

Also, I'm not sure if I should reference the fully qualified fragment name (e.g. `com.mycompany.calcthis.calcfragment`) or the short fragment name (e.g. `CalcFragment`).

What's happening is if I accept the Android Studio red bulb help to refactor the code for adding one of the fragments inside the `adapter.addFrag(new fragment name(), "title")` clause, it causes the other to be considered an error and it immediately underlines the other one as an error. It only accepts one of the two fragments without error. Weird!

Here's my code:

```
package thirtyeightdreams.com.calcthis;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Calculate extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculate);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new CalcFragment(), "Calculate");
        adapter.addFrag(new TogetherFragment(), "Together");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(PayForFragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a screen shot of the tip being offered. Notice both fragments are underlined with a red line:
[image]

So I accept the tip to refactor the code and it fixes that one:
[image]

But then if I accept the same tip code for the line that is still red, the other one that I just fixed becomes red.

So I'm trying to understand how to fix it so I can have multiple fragments listed here.

My overall goal is to have a particular fragment appear when a particular tab is clicked on.

Thanks

Comment: Also, I get this error when trying to run it: Error:(67, 26) error: no suitable method found for add(CalcFragment)
method List.add(Fragment) is not applicable
(actual argument CalcFragment cannot be converted to Fragment by method invocation conversion)
method List.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method Collection.add(Fragment) is not applicable
(actual argument CalcFragment cannot be converted to Fragment by method invocation conversion)

Comment: I think the problem has to do with that I'm mixing version of fragment classes. I noticed this error - wrong 1st argument type required: ‘android.support.v4.app.Fragment’ when expanding the error. I tried replacing with android.app.Fragment classes but not sure if this is more modern or older version.

Comment: Do you have to use `PayForFragment ` in defining your `addFrag()` method? Have you tried using `public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing [android.support.v4.app.Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uibCk.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Try to import all of your fragments
using `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`